# Jquery: Image won't change after being clicked, instead it stays at hover image..

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, load

I want to change my image onhover then when i click the hovered image, i will change it to another image..
But, the problem is when i clicked the onhover image, it will stay with onhover image instead of changing it to clicked image..

There are 2 files in my project here comp-profile.html and about.html, below is the source code:

comp-profile.html:

```
$("#Content-header-wrapper #link1").unbind("hover").hover(function(){
            alert("asd");
            $("#Content-header-wrapper #link1").attr("src","Images/Content/link-about-hover.png");
        },function(){
            $("#Content-header-wrapper #link1").attr("src","Images/Content/link-about.png");
    });
$("#Content-header-wrapper #link1").unbind("click").click(function(){
        $("#Content-header-wrapper #link1").attr("src","Images/Content/link-comp-profile.png");
        $("#Content-header-wrapper #link2").attr("src","Images/Content/link-contact.png");
        $("#Content-header-wrapper #link1").attr("alt","link-comp-profile");
        $("#Content-header-wrapper #link2").attr("alt","link-contact");
        $("#Content-header").html("<img src='Images/Content/header-about.png' alt='header-about' width='273px' height='41'/>");
        $("#Content-fill").empty();
        $("#Content-fill").load("about-content.html");
        $("#Content").fadeOut(0);
        $("#Content").animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'},"slow");
    });
```

about.html:

```
$("#Content-header-wrapper #link1").unbind("hover").hover(function(){
            $("#Content-header-wrapper #link1").attr("src","Images/Content/link-comp-profile-hover.png");
        },function(){
            $("#Content-header-wrapper #link1").attr("src","Images/Content/link-comp-profile.png");
    });
```

Another weird think is that, whenever i hover the image in about.html it still alert the "asd"...

Please help me with this.. ^^

Answer (score 0):

`hover` is not an event so you cannot unbind it, you need to remove the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

```
$("#Content-header-wrapper #link1").off("mouseenter mouseleave").hover(function () {
    $("#Content-header-wrapper #link1").attr("src", "Images/Content/link-comp-profile-hover.png");
}, function () {
    $("#Content-header-wrapper #link1").attr("src", "Images/Content/link-comp-profile.png");
});
```